# Valor de variable en comentarios de un método

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Me gustaría saber si existe la posibilidad de agregar en los comentarios de un método el valor de una variable del código, ejemplo:

```
static string defaultDateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";

/// <summary>
/// Convierte un string a Date con el siguiente formato: defaultDateFormat.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dateInput">Valor a convertir.</param>
/// <returns>Date.</returns>
public static DateTime ConvertToDate(string dateInput)
{
    DateTime ret = DateTime.MinValue;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateInput, defaultDateFormat, null, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out ret)) { }
    return ret;
}
```

Es decir que al momento de usar el método se muestre el siguiente mensaje:

> Convierte un string a Date con el siguiente formato: dd/MM/yyyy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes, ya que el valor de esa variable existe sólo en tiempo de ejecución (cuando ya se compiló el programa), por lo contrario, los comentarios son obviados por el compilador, o sea, que no existen en tiempo de ejecución, por lo cual ni los comentarios son conscientes del valor de tu variable ni tu programa es consciente de los comentarios.